# iframe onload not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, mobile-safari

The `onload` event is working in Chrome, but not working in Safari. `resizeIframe(this);` is not being called.

```js
function renderList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
    var htmlStr = '<iframe id="f_' + id + '" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>';
    $(".my-cards").html(htmlStr);
  }
}

function resizeIframe(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: There is no `src` attribute on the `iframe`, so I don't see how the `load` event will fire at all - even in Chrome.

Comment: I'm Dynamically adding dom elements inside the iframe. like that var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
    meta.content = "IE=edge";
    head.appendChild(meta);
But it's perfectly working in chrome. Can't understood why not in safari

Comment: And normally i'm tried with an iframe onload simple example, That is also not worked. So that i'm asking, Is safari browser supporting iframe onload attribute?